# How much freedom does TensorFlow take away from pure Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get into ML and Deep Learning. It's been educational for me to start out with this in Python rather than a different language where I would may lose focus of exactly what is really going on. I've looked across the internet for tutorials on Neural Networks in Python and TensorFlow seems to be *dominating* the field, is this true? I enjoy doing things on my own (pure language) but I haven't seen a lot of tutorials that teach this that don't involve TensorFlow or some other library (Keras, Scikit-learn, etc.); so now I've decided to look into these.

The question I have is: does TensorFlow take away from pure Python?

For example, this code is from a [tutorial](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/10/simple-neural-network-python.html) and it creates a simple neural net that predicts what the output will be based on three numbers (NOTE: I haven't checked how this code trains and could probably make this better if I did I were to make it again myself):

```py
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork():

    def __init__(self):
        # seeding for random number generation
        np.random.seed(1)

        #converting weights to a 3 by 1 matrix with values from -1 to 1 and mean of 0
        self.synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3, 1)) - 1

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        #applying the sigmoid function
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoid_derivative(self, x):
        #computing derivative to the Sigmoid function
        return x * (1 - x)

    def train(self, training_inputs, training_outputs, training_iterations):

        #training the model to make accurate predictions while adjusting weights continually
        for iteration in range(training_iterations):
            #siphon the training data via  the neuron
            output = self.think(training_inputs)

            #computing error rate for back-propagation
            error = training_outputs - output

            #performing weight adjustments
            adjustments = np.dot(training_inputs.T, error * self.sigmoid_derivative(output))

            self.synaptic_weights += adjustments

    def think(self, inputs):
        #passing the inputs via the neuron to get output   
        #converting values to floats

        inputs = inputs.astype(float)
        output = self.sigmoid(np.dot(inputs, self.synaptic_weights))
        return output


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #initializing the neuron class
    neural_network = NeuralNetwork()

    print("Beginning Randomly Generated Weights: ")
    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    #training data consisting of 4 examples--3 input values and 1 output
    training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                                [1,1,1],
                                [1,0,1],
                                [0,1,1]])

    training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

    #training taking place
    neural_network.train(training_inputs, training_outputs, 15000)

    print("Ending Weights After Training: ")
    print(neural_network.synaptic_weights)

    user_input_one = str(input("User Input One: "))
    user_input_two = str(input("User Input Two: "))
    user_input_three = str(input("User Input Three: "))

    print("Considering New Situation: ", user_input_one, user_input_two, user_input_three)
    print("New Output data: ")
    print(neural_network.think(np.array([user_input_one, user_input_two, user_input_three])))
    print("Wow, we did it!")
```

What does TensorFlow take away from this?

Thanks!

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: @Prune, ahh thanks, I will edit this question accordingly

Comment: @Prune I believe I have addressed this, but all feedback to how I write questions is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You still not asking specific programming problem. SO is not a regular discussion forum and your question is off-topic as primarily opinion based

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Is this question worth keeping then? I thought it might be helpful for not just me, but maybe others as well?. Maybe this is not the right forum though. Thanks for the tip :D I will keep it for a little longer and see if maybe anyway responds but otherwise I'll follow your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this I am going to share my thoughts. I chose to take the route of pure python with nothing like TensorFlow. I heard from other people that TensorFlow could take away an understanding that beginners need. At first, it was really hard for me to find anything that could help, but then I found everything all at once. The following links are the resources I used.

**Theory:**

The first 2-4 videos of this series by 3blue1brown: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUvTyaaNkzM&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr

All of the videos in this series by 3blue1brown: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk&list=PLZHQObOWTQDNU6R1_67000Dx_ZCJB-3pi

**Implementation:**

This video by the coding train: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc2IthslyzM&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6bCN8LKrcMa6zF4FPtXyXYj&index=8

Additional links for the calculus are: https://www.symbolab.com/cheat-sheets/Derivatives#, https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-partial.html

And this entire series by the coding train: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ7HLz9VYz0&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Y7MdSCaIfsxc561QI0U0Tb

**Summary**

And that is it, that is all I really needed to get started it is awesome! One more thing I should note is that I eventually ended up using [Processing.py](https://py.processing.org/), if you don't know what it is, **it is not a library for neural networks**, but instead allows for really easy graphics in python, there are functions like `ellipse` which just make a circle, this is the python implementation of what the coding train uses.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this answers your question. Personally I like to think of TensorFlow as the OpenCV of Machine Learning. It contains large number of libraries that help Data Scientists/Developers who want to get things done more quickly. For example, TensorFlow has Keras library which faciliaties that addition and modification of neural network layers, as well as functions such as ImageDataGenerator which helps loading the trining/verification data and categorizing it. In your code, you had to manually implement sigmoid_derivative() function. However, in Tensorflow the function is already written for you

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(150,150,3)),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3,3),
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3,3),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(16,activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

The code above shows a simple neural network to identify dogs and cats (so original..). Notice `activation='sigmoid'`? That's the sigmoid function that without TensorFlow I would've had to type manually, like you did.

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion do you think TensorFlow still lets you have a low-level understanding of what is going on? Also, I‘m just checking because it is the only question I have had when doing these; the derivative of the sigmoid is multiplied by the error because that gives us the gradient descent, correct?